# Lineinfile insertafter is not effecting

Tags: ansible

Running this playbook but insertafter is not effecting and regex is changing the line.

This is my `inputs.conf` file

```ini
# May require to run as root on some platforms.
[script://./bin/sshdChecker.sh]
disabled = true
interval = 3600
source = Unix:SSHDConfig
sourcetype = Unix:SSHDConfig


# May require to run as root on some platforms.
[script://./bin/update.sh]
disabled = true
interval = 86400
source = Unix:Update
sourcetype = Unix:Update


[script://./bin/uptime.sh]
disabled = true
interval = 86400
source = Unix:Uptime
sourcetype = Unix:Uptime


[script://./bin/version.sh]
disabled = true
interval = 86400
source = Unix:Version
sourcetype = Unix:Version


# This script may need to be modified to point to the VSFTPD configuration file.
[script://./bin/vsftpdChecker.sh]
disabled = true
interval = 86400
source = Unix:VSFTPDConfig
sourcetype = Unix:VSFTPDConfig
```

This is the playbook I'm running to modify the above file

```yaml
---
- name: changing line in file
  hosts: host
  become: true

  tasks:

    - name: change
      replace:
        path: /opt/splunkforwarder/etc/apps/Splunk_TA_nix/defaults/inputs.conf
        regexp: 'disabled = false'
        replace: 'disabled = true'
        backup: yes

    - name: insert
      ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
         path: /opt/splunkforwarder/etc/apps/Splunk_TA_nix/defaults/inputs.conf
           #regexp: '\[script://.*]'
           #search_string: '[script://.*]'
         insertafter: '#[script://.*]'
         line: 'index=linux'
         state: present
      with_items:
        - script://./bin/vmstat_metric.sh
        - script://./bin/update.sh
        - script://./bin/uptime.sh
        - script://./bin/version.sh
        - script://./bin/vsftpdChecker.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Your replace will have no effect, since all values are already `true`.
Besides that, as already pointed out, your use case to use `lineinfile` is not the best approach here. Using the template module is a better fit.

To solve your issue, loop the name of the scripts.

```yaml
- name: ensure every item has linux as the index
  lineinfile:
      path: /opt/splunkforwarder/etc/apps/Splunk_TA_nix/defaults/inputs.conf
      firstmatch: true
      insertafter: '.script://.{{ item }}.'
      line: 'index = linux # {{ item }}'
      state: present
  loop:
    - /bin/sshdChecker.sh
    - /bin/update.sh
    - /bin/uptime.sh
    - /bin/version.sh
    - /bin/vsftpdChecker.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

From your task I understand that you like to know via Ansible, "*How to install Splunk Technology Add-On (TA) for *nix in SplunkForwarder?*" or "*How to create a `inputs.conf` file for SplunkForwarder?*".

Because of "*... if you want to change multiple, similar lines ...*", I like to recommend to use the [`template` module – Template a file out to a target host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html) or the [`ini_file` module – Tweak settings in INI files](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ini_file_module.html) in order to

> *Manage (add, remove, change) individual settings in an INI-style file without having to manage the file as a whole ...*

in your specific case.

Since the structure of the `inputs.conf` is an INI-style file, a minimal example [idempotent](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#term-Idempotency) playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Set key=value in section (disable)
    ini_file:
      path: inputs.conf
      section: "{{ item }}"
      option: disabled
      value: true
    loop: # over sections in INI file
      - script://./bin/sshdChecker.sh
      - script://./bin/update.sh
      - script://./bin/uptime.sh
      - script://./bin/version.sh
      - script://./bin/vsftpdChecker.sh

  - name: Set key=value to section (add)
    ini_file:
      path: inputs.conf
      section: "{{ item }}"
      option: index
      value: linux
    loop: # over sections in INI file
      - script://./bin/vmstat_metric.sh
      - script://./bin/update.sh
      - script://./bin/uptime.sh
      - script://./bin/version.sh
      - script://./bin/vsftpdChecker.sh
```

will result into the requested output

```yaml
TASK [Set key=value in section (disable)] ***************
ok: [localhost] => (item=script://./bin/sshdChecker.sh)
ok: [localhost] => (item=script://./bin/update.sh)
ok: [localhost] => (item=script://./bin/uptime.sh)
ok: [localhost] => (item=script://./bin/version.sh)
ok: [localhost] => (item=script://./bin/vsftpdChecker.sh)

TASK [Set key=value to section (add)] *******************
ok: [localhost] => (item=script://./bin/vmstat_metric.sh)
ok: [localhost] => (item=script://./bin/update.sh)
ok: [localhost] => (item=script://./bin/uptime.sh)
ok: [localhost] => (item=script://./bin/version.sh)
ok: [localhost] => (item=script://./bin/vsftpdChecker.sh)
```

after a second run and a final file like

```ini
# May require to run as root on some platforms.
[script://./bin/sshdChecker.sh]
disabled = True
interval = 3600
source = Unix:SSHDConfig
sourcetype = Unix:SSHDConfig


# May require to run as root on some platforms.
[script://./bin/update.sh]
disabled = True
interval = 86400
source = Unix:Update
sourcetype = Unix:Update
index = linux


[script://./bin/uptime.sh]
disabled = True
interval = 86400
source = Unix:Uptime
sourcetype = Unix:Uptime
index = linux


[script://./bin/version.sh]
disabled = True
interval = 86400
source = Unix:Version
sourcetype = Unix:Version
index = linux


# This script may need to be modified to point to the VSFTPD configuration file.
[script://./bin/vsftpdChecker.sh]
disabled = True
interval = 86400
source = Unix:VSFTPDConfig
sourcetype = Unix:VSFTPDConfig
index = linux


[script://./bin/vmstat_metric.sh]
index = linux
```

To prevent the excessive usage of disk (I/O operations) and `loop`, it is recommended to evaluate "*How to template out the configuration file?*" and proceed further with a template.